# Running espresso test case using Bitbucket Pipelines

Tags: continuous-integration, bitbucket, android-espresso, ui-testing, bitbucket-pipelines

I am new to Bitbucket Pipelines and currently struggling with running test cases on that. I have an Android build which is now running correctly on Pipelines. But I am unable to find a way to run my espresso test case on it.

Anyone aware about how to do this, please suggest. Thanks already !

Comment: I am now using gitlab for this purpose, my problem is solved. Sorry for late update.

Comment: can you please share the details of how you did it?